# I want to embed a uml activity Diagram

Tags: doxygen, plantuml, doxywizard

I am trying to create an activity diagram of my code by embedding the UML syntax in code and using Doxygen with plant UML.
this is my  code

```
int add_numbers(int a, int b) {
    /** @startuml*/
    /** start */
    return a + b;
    /** @enduml*/
}
```

and this is my error
[Syntax Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B2eY5.png)

the objective is to create the documenrtation regardless of the method and have it embedded in Software not in a sebarate section.

Comment: I don't use Doxygen, but from the documentation at https://www.doxygen.nl/manual/commands.html#cmdstartuml it doesn't look like you can split the PlantUML commands over multiple lines of comments (the whole thing has to be inside the comment). Also, I am pretty certain that Java syntax (`return a+b`) isn't compatible with a PlantUML activity diagram. I see what you'd like to do, but as far as I know it's not possible. There may be some tools that can generate a PlantUML diagram from code, but I don't think doxygen supports that.

Comment: Which version of doxygen are you using? Didn't you get warnings like "warning: found */ without matching /* while inside a \startuml block! Perhaps a missing \enduml?" The uml block has to be in in one comment block and start with `@startuml` and end with `@enduml`.

Comment: I am using  rel-1.9.6, I was using rel-1.8.14 and getting the same warning yet it generates the figures I am not able to do that anymore